# How to compare 2 chronometers Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm looking to compare 2 chronometers which are strings like:

```
let time1 = "0' 47\" 0";
let time2 = "0' 46\" 9";
```

I tried **parseInt**, but it gives me 0 for both.

[the 2 strings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QmNT8.png)

Comment: Those are strings. They cannot be numbers without you writing your own parser.

Comment: How would you convert these strings, in human readable steps, to a single number?

Comment: @MichielDral It appears they're trying to turn them into a timespan (similar to .NET's `System.Timespan` class).

Comment: @TheIncorrigible I figured that after reading what a chronometer is, hahaha, do you know if the format is `hour' minute" second` ?

Comment: @MichielDral yes, that's the usual format

Comment: i added a picture to help :)

Comment: @MathiasBradiceanu You'll need to parse the strings down to seconds and compare the two values from there.  Then you can re-construct a new string to show the difference.

Comment: I created a small helper function for fun: https://jsfiddle.net/RokoCB/u6L4hra8/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nice try, but javascript is not as smart just yet ;)
It will see the first `0`, and assume that is what you are looking for.
You can try it in the chrome console: type `parseInt("8 anything here really 10 11 12 999")` will give you just `8`. Try putting anything instead of the `8`, and it will return that.

You'll want to first to take the numbers out of the string, which I normally do with a regular expression (For this I am assuming the first number is hours, the second is minutes and the third is seconds):

```
let extract_chronometer_seconds = (formatted_time) => {
  // Extract the number strings from formatted string
  let [match, hours_str, minutes_str, seconds_str] = formatted_time.match(/^(\d+)' (\d+)" (\d+)$/);
  // Because `.match` only returns strings, we still have to turn them into numbers with either `parseInt(str)` or `Number(str)`
  let hours = parseInt(hours_str);
  let minutes = parseInt(minutes_str);
  let seconds = parseInt(seconds_str);
  // Combine hours, minutes and seconds into one number
  let total_seconds = hours * (60 * 60) + minutes * (60) + seconds;
  return total_seconds;
}
```

I put it in a function, so you can use it like

```
let seconds1 = extract_chronometer_seconds(time1);
let seconds2 = extract_chronometer_seconds(time2);
// ... Do anything with `seconds1` and `seconds2`
```

Of course you can change the function to actually return the `hours`, `minutes` and `seconds` values, if you want to compare them other than just converting them to seconds.

Hope this helps! :)